# Laravel Mail, foreach loop inside build

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on an app which will send some forms links to some persons on desired time. i have used a queue for that. but the problem is, each participant has their unique links. i have to set them all into a single queue. so i have used laravel Mail class. have reached by sending mail. but the problem i am facing is email is successfully sent to the persons. but the link i have attached was sent same to all of them, it was the data of last array key. means the last participant's link was shared with them all.

Here is my Mail class build function, where i have used foreach to send different links to different participants.

```
public function build()
{
    // return $this->view('emails.formlink')
    //             ->subject('Participant Form Link');

    foreach ($this->linktoShare as $key => $value) {
        $participant    = InhouseParticipants::get(['id', 'email'])->find($value->participant_id);
        $this->mailData = $value->toArray();
        $this->to($participant->email)
            ->view('emails.formlink')
            ->subject('Participant Form Link')
            ->with($this->mailData);
    }
}
```

in the view, i have passed link as `$mailData['link']`. kindly suggest me if you have any solutions.

Comment: can you show other codes too so that we can understand a problem? Because of this information its hard to understand!

Comment: Can you please dump this array $this->linktoShare ?

Comment: @FarazIrfan it's a multidimensional array with the different links with participants. i have fetched participant details from their Ids to get their email address, and passed that link in with. all data is perfect. i have printed all, tested links. all are fine. but the mail i am sending, uses the last array values.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Queue has the copy of your previously run jobs, so need to restart the queue when you change code block that will push to queue, so here is your solution.

Navigate to you project directory and run

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

and dispatch jobs again, it will fix the issue.